# Where should I consult about choosing a name for an open-source project?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have an open-source project that I'm having trouble defining. Where is the appropriate place to ask for advice?

Comment: With the possible exception of a chat room, nowhere on Stack Exchange I'm afraid.

Comment: Whatever it is, make sure the name is a verb, then turn it into a noun by adding "r" onto the end.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Stack Exchange works best for asking about "technical support" -style issues; typically very *specific* problems that can be authoritatively resolved within the space of a post.

Brainstorming a name for your product might work in a more-open threaded discussion forum (or possibly a chat room), but the Stack Exchange Q&A format is not a good fit for a discussion of this type.

Sorry I do not have better news for you.

Comment: What if I already have a name but i'm trying to find the right technical definition for the project?

Comment: @YoavKadosh Unless you are having [trouble with the English language](http://english.stackexchange.com), this type of collaborative, open-ended discussion is not a good fit for this Q&A format. It just doesn't fit  under the premise of *"what is the correct answer to this question?"* for which Stack Exchange was created.

Comment: I see, thank you for clarifying that.